# Share sheetfed scanner over network

Tags: remote-access, usb, network-share

Greetings, I have a problem with sharing of sheetfed scanner (Panasonic KV-S...). How can I network this type of USB device between multiple computers in our LAN? Our supplier recommends software tool [USB to Ethernet Connector](http://www.eltima.com/products/usb-over-ethernet/) . Does anybody have any experience with this tool? Or maybe any other solution? Thanks...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are able to connect it to a Linux box and if your scanner is supported, Sane (http://www.sane-project.org/) has pretty good support for sharing scanners on a network. There is a windows client available, but I dont know if there is any server support ...

Good luck !

Answer (score 0):

I can recommend USBtoEthernet Connector, you can try its demo from product page, check [wiki](http://wiki.eltima.com/user-guides/usb2ethernet.html) or contact developer support team if you have any questions…

** My usage scenario was in accessing USB under Hyper-V session and they even developed custom solution (secure backup over net) for my client.

Hope this helps)